# Android how to load many image to ListView without getting Out Of Memory?

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I have a ListView, each row have an ImageView to load a small icon. When I scroll down the list, new rows will be load dynamically. But when I scroll up, the old rows just show up which mean all the image in ImageView are cache in the memory right? Now if I scroll down long enough, the memory to store bitmap image will be full and I get Out Of Memory Error. So what's the best way to load Image to ListView in this situation?

EDIT: Is there a way for me to clear all bitmap image  in memory when my activity finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below two link for that, it may help you.

[Lazy List](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

[Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with showing or setting bitmaps,
use `bitmap.recycle() and bitmap = null`
this will help to Garbage Collector to clean memory.